# Difference between addOnGlobalLayoutListener and onWindowFocusChanged?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, android-relativelayout

Currently  I have several views and the screen is divided into two section

Example:

```
text1     image1

text2

text3

text4
```

The problem is , if the image1 is tall , it will overlap the textview on left side, so I use to left of to force the textview width not exceed the imageview's left.

```
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView1"
```

however, every textview are aligned to left of the imageview as  I  do not  know the height of it until the view is created . And I want all textview below the baseline of imageview remove the layout rules of `android:layout_toLeftOf`

So I search for the solution and find two ways ?

```
1.onWindowFocusChanged

2.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener
```

Both can get the yaxis of the view.

The problems are:

```
 1. what is the difference between them ?

 2. I tried approach 2 , but it is not working, how to fix it?
```

Code:

```
        image.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ImgY = image.getY();
        }
    });

    lng.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (lng.getY() > ImgY) {
                lng.removeRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF);
            }
        }
    });
```

The error is I would like to set a global value to store the y of imageview, but it warns `The final local variable ImgY cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type` Also, the removeRule function return

```
 The method removeRule(int) is undefined for the type TextView
```

Thanks a lot for helping.